# Time-travel series where the Time Patrol are the bad guys and the protagonist falls in love with their leader's daughter

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

Some years ago I read a time-travel series that I'd like to find again, but I can't recall the name of it.

Here's what I recall:

- It was about some kind of time-travel-related authority figures: Time Patrol, Time Police, Temporal...Something?  I don't remember the name.  (I've looked up similar terms and found nothing so far.)
- The protagonist wasn't one of these authority figures.  He was in opposition to them, and he was the good guy, whereas the time police/patrol/authority/whatever were the bad guys.
- The protagonist fell in love with the (adult) daughter of the main Time Patrol/Police/Whatever figure.
- At some point later in the series, around the third or fourth book, I think, the protagonist and said daughter were escaping together.  In the course of events, the protagonist got the daughter pregnant.  Later, the main Time (Whatever) authority figure managed to get his daughter back.  I remember the specific point that he had the fetus removed from her and placed into an artificial womb.
- Based on when I read this series, I think it would have to have been written no later than 1993, but it could have been much earlier, of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is probably the [*Time Police*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?3607) series by Warren Norwood and Mel Odom (the first two are credited only to Warren Norwood on the covers).

The first book [*Vanished*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6376) (1988) begins with translator Jackson Dubchek set up as an assassin by corrupt **Time Police** Captain Slye.  This leaves him on the run and turns him into an opposition figure for the rest of the series.

The blurb on the first book reads:

> The Second Republic was mercilessly efficient.  It controlled the press, the state, the rights of its citizens.  Then one day it captured the secret of time travel.
>
> Now the Second Republic could control the past, piece by piece, slowly changing it to make sure that they would never lose their grasp on history. The **Time Police were the agents of oppression** of the Second Republic, dedicated to protecting its version of the past.
>
> Jackson Dubchek was a researcher, an ordinary citizen, too insignificant to warrant the attention of the Time Police until he stumbled onto the truth behind their work. **He is determined to undo what they have done.**  Now the Time Police are after him.  Jackson must go on the run to escape them and there is no place for him to go but into the past!

Jackson had previously met Suzanne Brelmer socially, and in fact it was she who recruited him for Temporal Projects; they have the beginnings of a connection that will get deeper as the series progresses.  Suzanne was in charge of the mission on which Jackson was scapegoated, doesn't believe that he was actually involved, and is trying to clear his name.

Suzanne is the **daughter of Praetor Centurion Friz Brelmer**, who largely runs the Time Police, though he is not properly in control of Captain Slye, and is subject to political pressure from above. (Praetor Centurion Lieutenant Colonel Brelmer, if you piss off his secretary.)  He does not start out as necessarily evil, though the actions that Temporal Projects are undertaking at the demands of their political masters are problematic, but he becomes much more relentless in his opposition to Dubchek as the series progresses.

The bit about the artificial womb comes from the third book [*Stranded*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6378) (1989) after Jackson has gotten Suzanne pregnant:

> "Remove the fetus," Brelmer said, surprised at the coldness in his voice.
>
> "You mean abort it?" Hoban seemed incredulous.
>
> No.  He could never kill anything that belonged to Suzanne.  But this child had to be Dubchek's.  Perhaps it had even been fathered back in the past for some reason not yet fathomed.  Until he was able to weigh out the repercussions of the child's conception, he would remove it from Suzanne's life.  It would be one less guilt she would have to live with.
>
> "No," Brelmer said.  "Keep it alive, but in an **artificial womb**."

[image: Cover of "Time Police: Vanished"]
[image: Cover of "Time Police: Trapped!"]
[image: Cover of "Time Police: Stranded"]

Interestingly, both [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/series/142655-time-police) and ISFDb list a fourth book *Refugee*, which ISFDb records as "unpublished" even though it has a publisher, ISBN and price.  The only comments about it on Goodreads are a couple of questions about finding it.

Comment: That's definitely it.  As soon as I saw that name Suzanne, it rang a bell.  Beautifully identified!